# Using quote in Clojure

Tags: clojure

Quoting in clojure results in non-evaluation. `':a` and `:a` return the same result. What is the difference between ':a and :a ? One is not evaluated and other evaluates to itself... but is this same as non-evaluation ?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Do you mean "How does the Clojure Reader work?" What kind of explanation would answer your question? The fact is that keywords evaluate to themselves. What does "how" mean in that context?

Comment: I agree. Its more of a " is it same as a non-evaluaton". Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. `':a` is shorthand for `(quote :a)`.
2. `(eval '(quote form))` returns `form` by definition. That is to say, if the Clojure function `eval` receives as its argument a list structure whose first element is the symbol `quote`, it returns the second element of said list structure without transforming it in any way (thus it is said that the quoted form is not evaluated). In other words, **the behaviour `eval` dispatches to when its argument is a list structure of the form `(quote foo)` is that of returning `foo` unchanged, regardless of what it is**.
3. When you write down the literal `:a` in your programme, it gets *read in* as the keyword `:a`; that is, the concrete piece of text `:a` gets converted to an in-memory data structure which happens to be called the `:a` keyword (Lisp being homoiconic means that occasionally it is hard to distinguish between the textual representation of Lisp data and the data itself, even when this would be useful for explanatory purposes...).
4. The in-memory data structure corresponding to the literal `:a` is a Java object which exposes a number of methods etc. and which has the interesting property that the function `eval`, when it receives this data object as an argument, returns it unchanged. In other words, **the keyword's "evaluation to itself" which you ask about is just the behaviour `eval` dispatches to when passed in a keyword as an argument**.
5. Thus when `eval` sees `':a`, it treats it as a quoted form and returns the second part thereof, which happens to be `:a`. When, on the other hand, `eval` sees `:a`, it treats it as a keyword and returns it unchanged. The return value is the same in both cases (it's just the keyword `:a`); the evaluation process is slightly different.
6. Clojure semantics -- indeed Lisp semantics, for any dialect of Lisp -- are specified in terms of the values returned by and side-effects caused by the function `eval` when it receives various Lisp data structures as arguments. Thus the above explains what's actually meant to happen when you write down `':a` or `:a` in your programme (code like `(println :a)` may get compiled into efficient bytecode which doesn't actually code the function `eval`, of course; but the semantics are always preserved, so that it still acts *as if* it was `eval` receiving a list structure containing the symbol `println` and the keyword `:a`).
7. **The key idea here is that regardless of whether the form being evaluated is `':a` or `:a`, the keyword data structure is constructed at read time; then when one of these forms is evaluated, that data structure is returned unchanged -- although for different reasons.**

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation Michal. So eval will look at the type of ':a' and as its a keyword will return :a ?

Comment: @Icarus: You're welcome. And yes, eval returns `:a` unchanged because it knows that's what it's supposed to do with keywords. Internally this is actually implemented as a class-based dispatch in the compiler, utilising the facilities for class-based dispatch provided by the JVM; but that's an implementation detail.

Comment: I think 2. should be (eval (quote form))

Comment: @JonChesterfield No, it should be `(eval '(quote form))`, as it is right now in the answer. `(eval (quote form))` evalutes `form` (the `quote` prevents `form` from being evaluted *before* it is passed to `eval`, as it otherwise would be, because `eval` is just a function). You can check this at the REPL: `(eval (quote (+ 1 2 3))) ;=> 6`, `(eval '(quote (+ 1 2 3))) ;=> (+ 1 2 3)`. It might have been better to write `(eval (list 'quote form))`, though.

Comment: To expand on the final sentence of the above, I think there are pros and cons to both `(eval '(quote form))` and `(eval (list 'quote form))` as an example here; ultimately, though, the important part, as far as this answer is concerned, is the shape of the argument that gets passed to `eval`, and when writing the answer I suppose I thought `(eval '(quote form))` made it slightly more immediately apparent. In any case, the longhand symbol `quote` is supposed to be part of what gets passed to `eval`, and indeed it is in `(eval '(quote form))`.

Comment: @MichałMarczyk I follow. Thank you for the clarification