# Lisp: Evaluation of quotes

Tags: lisp, eval, interpreter, evaluation, quote

Which of the following expressions has correct lisp syntax?

```
(+ 1 (quote 1))
==> 1 (???)
(+ 1 (eval (quote 1))
==> 2
```

I'm currently writing my own lisp interpreter and not quite sure how to handle the quotes correct. Most lisp interpreters I've had a look at evaluate both expressions to "2". But shouldn't the quote be not evaluated at all and thereby only the second one be a legal expression? Why does it work then anyway? Is this some kind of syntactical sugar?

Comment: A good related question is [What is the difference between 1 and '1 in Lisp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966765/what-is-the-difference-between-1-and-1-in-lisp).

Answer (score 5):

Barring special forms, most Lisps evaluate the arguments first, then apply the function (hence the eval-and-apply phrase).

Your first form `(+ 1 '1)` would first evaluate its arguments `1` and `'1`.  Constant numerics evaluate to themselves, and the quote evaluates to what it quotes, so you'd be left applying `+` to `1` and `1`, yielding `2`.

```
eval: (+ 1 (quote 1))
eval 1st arg:  1 ==> 1
eval 2nd arg: '1 ==> 1
apply: (+ 1 1) ==> 2
```

The second form is similar, the unquoted 1 will just go through `eval` once, yielding `1` again:

```
eval: (+ 1 (eval '1))
eval 1st arg: 1 ==> 1
eval 2nd arg: (eval '1)
  eval arg:    '1 ==> 1
  apply: (eval 1) ==> 1
apply: (+ 1 1) ==> 2
```

Answer (score 3):

Numbers evaluate to themselves so `(quote 1)` is the same as `1`.

Comment: Not "is the same," but "evaluates to."

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Indeed, in a macro, `(quote 1)` and `1` might produce different behavior.